# MySql DELETE usando SUBQUERY con misma tabla en FROM

Tags: mysql, sql

Sistema gestor de bases de datos:
MySql 5.7.11

Estoy tratando de crear una consulta SQL para eliminar todos los registros que cumplen con la siguiente condición:

Se trata de un sistema de tarifas, una tabla tarifa esta relacionada con la tabla precios en una relación uno-a-muchos, y cada precio se relaciona con un producto.

Debido a que las tarifas se crean mediante acciones en lote a veces en una tarifa quedan registrados varios precios para un mismo producto. Mi intención es mantener en cada tarifa solo el ultimo precio(el de mayor id) para cada producto y eliminar los precios anteriores, para ello estoy utilizando la siguiente consulta:

```
DELETE p 
    FROM  ges_precio as p 
    WHERE p.tarifa_id = :tarifa 
          and id < 
              (select max(a.id) as id 
               from ges_precio  a 
               where a.tarifa_id = :tarifa 
                     and p.producto_id = a.producto_id 
               )
```

Pero estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:

> You can't specify target table 'p' for update in FROM clause

He tratado de encapsular la subquery en otro select y usar un alias para solucionarlo como viene explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969601/5544616) pero tampoco funciona.

Estoy buscando una forma de realizar la consulta, sin usar una subquery en el `FROM` que consulte a la tabla precio.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Voy a poner un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor lo que pretendo hacer, esta es la tabla ges_precio:

> id | importe | tarifa_id | producto_id
>
> 1 | 24 | 1 | 24
>
> 2 | 16 | 1 | 53
>
> 3 | 18 | 1 | 24

Ahora mismo la tarifa 1 consta de tres precios, el problema es que dos de ellos hacen referencia al mismo producto 24, en este caso quiero desechar el precio mas antiguo para esta tarifa y el producto 24, es decir tras usar la consulta la tabla debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

> id | importe | tarifa_id | producto_id
>
> 2 | 16 | 1 | 53
>
> 3 | 18 | 1 | 24

Comment: Si tienes la clave como auto-incremental ten en cuenta que según como la hayas creado hacer `MAX` en ella no te garantiza obtener el último valor generado.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: Utilizo TABLE como estrategia de generación así que no debe haber problema con eso, igualmente gracias por el consejo. He editado y añadido un ejemplo a la pregunta para que se entienda mejor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He tenido varias veces este tipo de problema (mantener el último registro de una relación). La forma que lo he solucionado casi siempre ha sido con tablas temporales y queries anidadas.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
  SELECT id FROM ges_precio 
  WHERE tarifa_id = ?? AND product_id = ??; -- [1]

DELETE FROM ges_precio 
  WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM temp) 
  AND product_id = ??; -- [2]

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp; -- [3]
```

De este forma:

1. Creas una tabla temporal con todos los precios para una tarifa y producto específico.
2. Eliminas todos los elementos que sean menores al último precio (`MAX(id)`)
3. Borras la tabla temporal.

**Actualización:**

Debido al tema de la eficiencia que propone Javi2EE, escribo algunas propuestas de mejoras que se me vienen a la cabeza:

Primero, las tablas temporales son tablas que existen en memoria volátil durante la ejecución de la query, tienen un tamaño máximo y son eficientes en el uso, ya que no utilizan disco ([leer sección temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html))

En el caso de que corra unas pocas veces al día (en un cron de limpieza, por ejemplo). Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
  SELECT MAX(id) as id, tarifa_id, producto_id 
  FROM ges_precio 
  GROUP BY tarifa_id, producto_id; -- Crear una tabla con solo los id de precio más altos, así se baja la cantidad total de filas de la tabla temporal.

DELETE g FROM ges_precio g
  WHERE id < (SELECT id FROM temp t WHERE t.tarifa_id = g.tarifa_id AND t.producto_id = g.producto_id ); -- y se borra usando un INNER JOIN con la temporal

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp; -- [3]
```

---

Otra opción es utilizar variables en la conexión en vez de tablas temporales, así podrías correr esta query varias veces, sin la preocupación de utilizar muchas tablas temporales. Ejemplo:

```
SET @id_temp = NULL;

SELECT MAX(a.id) INTO @id_temp 
  FROM ges_precio
  WHERE tarifa_id = :tarifa 
    AND producto_id = :producto_id;

DELETE FROM ges_precio 
  WHERE id < @id_temp;
```

de esta forma solo creas una variable en la sesión de conexión con el valor necesario y lo utilizas posteriormente para borrar.

Espero haber ayudado con esto último.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Pablo, es la primera solución real que veo ante esta situación, aunque me preocupa un poco el tema de la eficiencia de esta consulta ya que las tarifas constan de decenas de miles de productos, y no se como reaccionara la base de datos al tener que crear tantas tablas temporales.

Comment: @Javi2EE actualizaré el post con unas mejoras que se me ocurren.

Comment: crack!! muchas gracias por la ampliación, de las tres soluciones la segunda es justo lo que necesitaba. Hay un pequeño fallo, falta la g en `DELETE g FROM ges_precio g`. Un millón de gracias